# Is my ASUS ZenBook’s sound card capable of recording two channels in stereo?

Tags: laptop, audio, sound-card, asus-laptop, headphone-jack

My laptop (ASUS ZenBook running Windows 10) has a combo jack for audio and mic. It has no separate sound card, just motherboard in bulk. This laptop has literally one jack hole that has a  4 ring “combo jack.”

I am looking into possibility of making stereo jack by soldering. The question is can I know without looking on motherboard is my laptop capable of recording two channels?

Is there a way to get to know if my laptop has only physically one audio input or is it mono in the way that the DAC itself is mono? How probable is such scenario?

Is there a way to get any more information about it than device manager can provide?

Comment: Commonly, the inputs and outputs of the laptop are stereo. But for you to listen (or record) to stereo, you need to make sure the plug you insert in is stereo.

The mono plug has 1 black ring, while the stereo plug has 2 black rings (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY8D0.png).

Once, making sure you're using the stereo plug, you can test the left and right channels with this video (https://youtu.be/e8ODm-F9-IM), which will play alternating sounds between the left channel and the right channel.

Comment: @RogérioDec you should post that as an answer.

Comment: I already did, but the answer was disqualified by @JakeGould...

Comment: I edited post to specify, unfortunately @RogérioDec misunderstood my question - number of plug rings is 4, so called combo jack. That means stereo output and mono input. The question was how to check whether motherboard itself is able to analyse stereo

Comment: @Burgi And just to qualify it, I didn’t “disqualify” more I stated the question was quite vague to begin with. And now that the original poster states, “…number of plug rings is 4…” It’s even less appropriate in this case. A well intentioned answer to a question that was vaguely worded.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to get a partial answer somewhere else - most common laptops should have stereo output on the motherboard regardless of number of physical channels accesible via ports. I wasn't able to verify that in my laptop yet.